# Unexpected character "EOF" Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

faced such an error with minimum code. Could someone say where should I look to solve it?

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of chosenEvents">
    <p>{‌{event}}</p>
</div>
```

ts:

```
chosenEvents = ['Meeting', 'Easter'];
```

Comment: Strangely, it works just fine for me. Check this [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5zjnxh?file=app%2Fbutton-overview-example.html). Initially it was giving me the same error. But then I moved a few things here and there and then reverted everything back. And it started working. Not sure why this unexpected behavior.

Comment: I'm definitely sure that the problem is inside Angular. Because I have a completed project and it's not the first time when I use *ngFor. But why it throws such an error exactly only in this place. Additionally it's a component which works fine with bigger code, but when I minimize it to simple div with p - it throws the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally got it with my colleague's help. The problem was exactly in brackets. I copy pasted the code from another resource and those brackets apparently have another **symbol character code** while look the same as normal ones. Retyping them all by myself has solved the problem.